# I got this error using ado.net data services "An error occurred while processing this request."

Tags: 2010

Any idea?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PortalCoporativoDataContext msdc = new PortalCoporativoDataContext(new Uri("http://win-j8t24f4b519/MySite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"));

  var excitingAnnouncements = from announcement in msdc.Announcements
                                        //where announcement.Title.EndsWith("!")
                                        select announcement;

  List<AnnouncementsItem> allAnnouncements = msdc.Announcements.ToList();

  foreach (var announcement in excitingAnnouncements)
  {
    announcement.Title += "!!";
    msdc.UpdateObject(announcement);
  }

  msdc.SaveChanges();
}
```

I got this on the Event Log:

> Event code: 3005  Event message: An
>   unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 10/4/2010 9:52:36 PM 
>   Event time (UTC): 10/5/2010 2:52:36 AM
>   Event ID:
>   581ab0098f024b7db0354e2754aa0cf7 
>   Event sequence: 8  Event occurrence: 1
>   Event detail code: 0    Application
>   information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1828559168/ROOT-2-129307206403076171
>
> ```
> Trust level: WSS_Minimal 
> Application Virtual Path: / 
> Application Path: K:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\803cbd1e1b-10ff-497d-80f1-c477f5867a9c\
>
> Machine name: WIN-J8T24F4B519    Process information: 
> Process ID: 1792 
> Process name: w3wp.exe 
> Account name: WIN-J8T24F4B519\Administrator
> ```
>
> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: DataServiceQueryException 
>       Exception message: An error occurred while processing this
>   request.    Request information: 
>       Request URL: http://win-j8t24f4b519/SitePages/Home.aspx
>
> ```
> Request path: /SitePages/Home.aspx 
> User host address: fe80::81c1:afd3:308:be9f/ 
> User: WIN-J8T24F4B519\Administrator 
> Is authenticated: True 
> Authentication Type: Negotiate 
> Thread account name: WIN-J8T24F4B519\Administrator
> ```
>
> Thread information: 
>       Thread ID: 10 
>       Thread account name: WIN-J8T24F4B519\Administrator 
>       Is impersonating: False 
>       Stack trace:    at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext
>   context, QueryComponents
>   queryComponents)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
>   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at
>   TrabajandoConDatos.UsandoDataServices.UsandoDataServicesUserControl.Button1_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Custom event details:

Comment: Is there any extra information in the eventlogs, such as authorisation errors or anything?

Comment: How is this code executed? Is this a desktop application? Does the user running it have read & write access to the Announcements
 list?

Comment: I am seeing this now myself...if I find out what happens I will add something.

Comment: ...within our environment it happens whenever we get too much data being returned than our page can appropriately display and handle.  Not sure how big our pipe is, but it's something on our list of things to look at.  Missed the comment edit window...